# Mixing stereo audio signal into one headphone can. For computer games

Tags: windows-7, audio, gaming

Hello I'm deaf in one ear but I love to play competitive FPS pc games. The problem is I can't pinpoint where people are in the game. Which makes it hard to shoot them in the face before they shoot me in the face.
I can kinda make do buy swing around wildly with a wide stereo spread to locate sounds, which is how i find things in real life like my cellphone.
What i wanted to try was to mix both channels into the same ear piece, but add an effect or some unique eq setting to only one of the channels to allow me to tell which side it represented.

help!

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been put on hold. If you think I'm seeking product recommendations then you are assuming that a product is the only way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

It's not easy to replicate the actual [Haas, or Precedence effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precedence_effect) [the time-delay & phase differences normally perceived by 2 ears] in headphones, even for non-hearing-impaired listeners.

That becomes far more difficult to do for only one side of the stereo field.

You could delay one channel by a set amount [I haven't checked the actual delay required to simulate this] but for a true '3D' image, the delay for a sound from the front is not the same as from 90˚ to one side. The delay would have to actively compare where the original sound source ought to be in the 360˚ horizontal plane & adjust accordingly.

It could possibly be done at source, but I don't see how it would be possible from a simple ready-processed stereo soundfield.

*Edit:*
The simplest solution may be to just sum the 2 sides to mono, with no delay. Then when any given sound is 'loudest' it is either directly in front or directly behind your character. There would be no way to tell which of those even by turning round, without Haas to help you, unless the game employs some equalisation changes depending on 'front' or 'rear' for non-hearing-impared listeners - as, of course, in simple stereo, Haas won't properly be assisting them either.

Comment: I'm not expecting to be able to exactly locate the equivalent of a pin drop from 30 meters away. What i need is rougher than that. simply adding bass to one channel will give a good impression of a sound that happens the other side of my head. There are some vids of this effect that work quite well and will be good enough.

Comment: I just need the correct program to do this! I could do it with the right cables, adapters, and some guitar multi effects. But this must be possible within the software world.

Comment: On Mac this could be simply done in CoreAudio with freebie plugins. I'm not sure how to achieve it on Windows. I know of no comparable plugin structure for Windows audio. Let me do some research...

Answer (score 3):

A small mixer with EQ controls and headphone jack, and a few cables and adapters, might work.

Assuming 1/8" stereo outputs from your sound card, a cable will be needed to send that into two separate channels on the mixer. I've used an 1/8" to RCA cable and a couple RCA to 1/4" adapters for just this. For instance, channel 1 is left, channel two is right.

Next, pan both channels to the same side (whichever you can hear with) and plug your headphones in and set up your levels on the soundcard, each mixer channel, the mixer's main volume, and the mixer's headphone outs (if separate). Note that a 1/4" to 1/8" adapter may also be needed for the headphones. Most decent phones come with this adapter.

Tweak EQ as desired. Recommend slightly cutting mids and boosting highs on one channel, while slightly boosting mid and cutting highs on the other. After some time I think you'll begin to acclimate to the difference in frequency response of the two channels.

Comment: Was hoping to avoid external equipment!

Comment: @hello I'm still researching… have feelers out on other SE sites to try find some Windows software solution to what is easy on Mac… bear with me...

Comment: Wow you are a gent. I really appreciate the effort. I've been looking at this all day too. I now know more about asio drivers than i really wanted to. The best i can come up with is program called Virtual audio Cable to pose as a fake soundcard for shuttling the game audio to a DAW of some description.

Comment: @hello Most welcome. I'm a sound engineer by trade & can't believe I don't already know how to do this on Windows. I have all the necessary things to be able to do it on Mac & assumed I could port my idea straight to Win… I've been trying to find a realtime, freeware, non-DAW/ASIO solution - but as yet I just have tumbleweed. See how it goes over the next day or so...

Comment: This is on hold now so I assume you can't reply. I did manage to get something up and running to test in game. I could distinguish between the two channels after simply adding loads of bass to one side. It introduces quite a lot of latency to one channel. So sounds would play on the right side (my good side) normally then the left sided channel plays after. It seems easier to make an external effects chain and not suffer these problems than to learn how to program and still not be guaranteed to be free of these latency problems. Thanks again though!

Comment: @hello I can still post, no worries. I've got it in my 'hold queue' waiting on some info on the other site - but so far just tumbleweed. Glad you got some semblance of what you were after, though. I'll keep this open for a while in case I get any info.

Comment: @hello - found this, but haven't researched it. Might be some use? http://jackaudio.org